# How to align text in the middle of a child row flexbox element. W

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align my text in the example below to middle and center of my box. Tried to use `align-content:center` or `justify-content:center` but it just messes with the `flex-basis`. Just like in the first box of the image I attached.

[image: What It Looks Like]

Here is my **html** code

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
 </div>
```

and here's the CSS

```
.box {
  display: flex;
      height: 350px;
     justify-content: space-evenly ;
    
}
.box > div{
  flex-basis: 25%;
   background-color: rgba(255, 235, 205, 0.336);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #eee0e0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
 }
.one{
  align-self: center;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align: center;` will centralize your text horizontally. If you want to also centralize your text vertically, you should set its `line-height` to be equal to its parent, which is `350px`.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 350px;
  justify-content: space-evenly ;
    
}
.box > div{
  flex-basis: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 235, 205, 0.336);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #eee0e0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align:center;    /*  new line  */
  line-height:350px;    /*  new line  */
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's strange that the line-height is equal to the parent and the text remains in the box not outside it. I will have to look more into it. This clearly worked but now I need to know why.

Comment: @DaisyLily I agree with you that using line-height to do this otherwise you should wrap the text in `div`s in a paragraph and make those `div`s flexbox or set their padding to `auto`. That is actually how you should do it !!

Answer (score 0):

Set to all children : `margin: auto; line-height:350px;`  It will set margin auto to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You try using `align-items:center` together with `justify-content:center` on all children divs and everything should work as intended.

```css
.box div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```